# Grails version differences

Tags: grails, comparison, version

I am finishing reading a book that I only now realized was written for Grails 1.1.1! We are on version 1.3.7 which seems light years away in Programming language terms.
Could anyone give a distilled comparison between Grails versions? What new features should I be aware that were added after 1.1.1?

Comment: To add to your version issues. Grails 2.0 will be released soon which is a pretty big release with lots of improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Each version ships with a set of Release Notes that outline the major changes. All of the major releases can be found on the [Grails archive download page](http://www.grails.org/download/archive/Grails).

Reading through the [latest documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html) will probably help, too.

Comment: Release notes and documentation are great, they are just too long. All I wanted was some bullet points of the main improvements of Grails since 1.1.1 so I could dive into the documentation for those features that my project could benefit from. Could you provide pointers to that?

Comment: They're actually not all that long; it probably wouldn't take more than a half hour to skim over all of them. A bulleted list would be nice and brief, but doesn't provide much value - many of the changes between releases are pretty important, and require some context (which is provided by the release notes, and wouldn't be available in a brief, bulleted list).